Should we adapt a version of Translation Golf to Chinese SE?
I’ve noticed that they do something called Translation Golf over at Spanish SE, which aims to increase activity and interaction among users. The rules can be found in the embedded link. 
Would it be feasible to introduce a modified version of Translation Golf here?

It is certainly feasible. 
All that is needed is a set of rules, people willing to come up with questions and participants.
I did ask a question asking for game ideas two years ago: Language game question ideas? You could add this idea to that thread too.

Honestly, we can just import most of the rules from the Spanish SE, just that we need to edit a bit regarding how we accept answers in Chinese characters

We can also specify whether we want answers to be in 文言文 or 白话文

Also an idea I wrote on the page I linked above: we could copy code golf in a way with users posting their used “language,” i.e.: learner, contemperory, literary, argot, classical - that might mitigate some differences in abilities.
